# Calculate the MLEs for betas of a logistic regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, maximum-likelihood, logit

An answer to a previous question on how to manually calculate the MLE for beta coefficients from a logistic regression was given the below answer (see previous question here: [How to manually calculate the intercept and coefficient in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243106/how-to-manually-calculate-the-intercept-and-coefficient-in-logistic-regression)).

> Take for example, the crosstab bellow shows how many males/females are
> in the honor class.

```
           |         female
       hon |      male     female |     Total  
-----------+----------------------+----------
         0 |        74         77 |       151 
         1 |        17         32 |        49 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |        91        109 |       200
```

> As mentioned above $∑_iy_ix_{ij}=∑_ip_ix_{ij}$ holds. The left hand side(LHS) is the
> expectation of the observations (y's in samples) and the right hand
> side(RHS) is the model's expectation.
>
> Assuming the function is $log(\frac{p1}{p1−p})=β_0+β_1x_i$ or
> equivalently $p=(\frac{1}{1+e^{β0+β1*x_i}})$ ($x_i$ represents the
> feature of the observation being a female, it is 1 if the observation
> is a female and 0 otherwise), obviously we know that the following two
> equations hold respectively when $X=1$ and when $X=0$ with the data
> shown above:
>
> $\frac{32}{109}=(\frac{1}{1+e^{β0+β1*x_1}})$
>
> $\frac{17}{91}=(\frac{1}{1+e^{β0+β1*x_0}})$
>
> So the intercept $(β_0)$ is -1.47 and the
> coefficient $(β_1)$ is 0.593. You can manually get it.

I am confused as to how they jumped from $\frac{32}{109}$ to getting the estimate for $(β_1)$. This seems like a useful way to estimate MLEs of parameters in a logistic regression. Can anyone help explain how they got to $(β_1)$ is 0.593 ?

Answer (score 3):

In this regression, then are only two observations and two fitted values, which are $\hat p_m=17/91$ for males and $\hat p_f=32/109$ for females.

Converting to the logit linear predictor scale gives:
$$\mbox{logit}(\hat p_m)= \hat\beta_0=\log\frac{ 17}{91-17} = \log\frac{17}{74}=-1.471$$
and
$$\mbox{logit}(\hat p_f)=\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1=\log\frac{32}{109-32} = \log\frac{32}{77}=-0.878$$
Hence
$$\hat\beta_1= -0.878 + 1.471 = 0.593$$

Note that this type of closed-form calculation only works for logistic regressions with a single categorical factor, or for models that are equivalent to regressions with a single categorical factor, such as factorial models with all possible interactions.
Logistic regressions with additive non-interacting terms do not admit closed-form estimators.